# Procedure to check for columns not null in a table if true then log into error column in the same table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an emp table where I do a cross-check:

```
eid int,
ename varchar,
desig varchar,
sal number,
validation_error varchar
```

After creating table I want to load data by checking for the column should not be null. If null it should log the error into the validation_error column.

Comment: for example:-
while loading if any column is not satisfying the constraint "not null" then it should capture the error into validation_error column.  
  
insert into emp values(1,'Fresher',5000) then it should capture the error into the validation_error as..

eid ename  desig         sal       validaiton_error
1                  fresher     5000     empname is not null

if more than one not null column condition is missing then it should capture the error with | symbole.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you can do this with computed column, like this:

```
create table emp (
    eid int
    , ename varchar(100)
    , desig varchar(100)
    , sal int
    , validation_error as (case when ename is null then 'ename is null ' else '' end)
            + (case when desig is null then 'desig is null ' else '' end)
            + (case when sal is null then 'sal is null ' else '' end)
);
```

Comment: Hi Dean, this is not my requirement am looking for... Looking for procedure which i want to run to check for 'not null' constraint validation, to populate in in validation error column.
Can you please tell, how this create statement will help me..